# Calculate positivity when no roots

Tags: polynomials

$$f(x) = (x-1)(x^2+2x+5)$$
$$f(x) = (x-1)(x^2+2x+5) > 0$$

$$x-1 > 0 \bigcap x^2+2x+5 > 0 $$

$$OR$$

$$x-1 < 0 \bigcap x^2+2x+5 < 0$$

The second factor doesn't have roots, and I am stuck after $$x^2+2x > -5$$

The negativity should be $$(-\infty,1)$$
The positivity should be $$(1,\infty)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Note that $$x^2+2x+5=(x+1)^2+4>0$$
then you should only look as$$x-1>0$$

Comment: So you are telling me that it will always be positive? I think I get it

Comment: yes $x^2+2x+5$ is always positive.

Comment: Thanks, how did you note that equality? Is it from experience or is there a rule? I mean the x^2+2x+5 = (x+1)^2+4

Comment: if $ax^2+bx+c$ don't have roots, then is always positive or always negative, then you Completing the Square. for see if is $>0$ or $<0$